# Do loop - variable does not change

Tags: list-manipulation

I got the follwing code which should add a '1' 100 times to an empty list.

```
plotVals = {}
Do[Append[plotVals, 1], {l, 1, Nmax}];
```

The output is again an empty list, why is this the case?

Comment: You're looking for `AppendTo`. `Append` doesn't modify the value of `plotVals`. Also take a look at `ConstantArray`.

Comment: check http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/19804#19804 (David Speyer's answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
Block[{plotVals = {}},
 Do[{plotVals = Append[plotVals, 1], Print[plotVals]}, {l, 1, 5}]]
```

You will lose information if you simply use `Append`, so you need to store it.

> {1}
>   {1,1}
>   {1,1,1}....

Also, Append/AppendTo is suicidal for speed, so rather use dynamically created list as,

```
Block[{plotVals = {}}, {Do[{plotVals = {plotVals, 1}}, {l, 1, 
    5}]}; plotVals]
```

> {{{{{{}, 1}, 1}, 1}, 1}, 1}

Which you can flatten. It will give a much better performance than `Append/AppendTo`

Comment: A small side note: Almost all built-in Mathematica functions are functional - not imperative; that is, those don't cause side effects, but rather only produce a return value. `Append` is one of those for which it is somewhat non-obvious before you get used to it. Once you do grok the mostly-functional paradigm of Mathematica and tools it provides for it, you probably want to stay away from imperative constructs most of the time.

Comment: The second example uses linked lists, which you can read more about [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25474/731).